# Should I call ReleaseIntArrayElements after GetIntArrayElements?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Should I call `ReleaseIntArrayElements` after `GetIntArrayElements`?

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_test_Example_func
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, jintArray javaArray) {
    jint *array = env->GetIntArrayElements(javaArray, JNI_FALSE);

    // do something with array        

    // is it necessarily to call ReleaseIntArrayElements in the end?
    //env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(javaArray, array, JNI_ABORT);
}
```

It seems there is no memory leak if I don't call `ReleaseIntArrayElements`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should. `GetIntArrayElements` may have created a copy of the data, or pinned the array to avoid having the data being moved by the garbage collector. That won't be undone until you call `ReleaseIntArrayElements`.

---

Also, `GetIntArrayElements(javaArray, JNI_FALSE)` is incorrect if you thought that it won't create a copy.
The second argument to `GetIntArrayElements` is a `jboolean*`, not a `jboolean`. It is an output parameter which after the function returns will point to a value indicating whether or not a copy was made.
In your case, `JNI_FALSE` just so happens to have the same value as `NULL`, so you're essentially doing `GetIntArrayElements(javaArray, NULL)` - that is, *"I'm not interested in knowing whether or not a copy was made"*.

Comment: so I can pass jboolean pointer there and use it later to release only if copy was made? `if (wasCopied) { env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(javaArray, array, JNI_ABORT); }`

Comment: No. The VM may pin the array instead of copying it. So then you won't have a copy but you should still call `Release` to unpin the array. Just always call `ReleaseIntArrayElements`. Trying to do so conditionally just complicates the code and introduces dependencies to a specific JVM implementation.