# c++ vector<int> to jintarray in JNI

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, jnienv

I am executing the below code snippet

```
vector<int> vec_data = {1,2,3,4,5}; 
jintArray jarray =  env->NewIntArray(vec_data.size());
jint* elements = env->GetIntArrayElements(jarray, 0);
for(int i=0; i<vec_data.size(); i++){
        elements[i] = vec_data[i];
        cout<<elements[i]<<endl;
        cout<<jarray[i]<<endl;
}
```

But i could see that jarray is always printing 0 or some grabage value, am i missing something here?
Basically i want to return jintArray from the vector.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56439313/should-i-call-releaseintarrayelements-after-getintarrayelements

Comment: Alternatively, you can just call `env->SetIntArrayRegion(jarray, 0, vec_data.size(), vec_data.data())`

Comment: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/blob/master/recipes/recipeNo045/c/recipeNo045_redux_VectorOfVectors.cc